# Instanciar un nuevo objeto

Tags: java

Hola soy nuevo en Java,

Estoy definiendo el siguiente diagrama UML en Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he creado casi todos los métodos que necesito pero además para la clase `Team` tengo que crear el objeto `StatisticsTeam` que le corresponde. Finalmente, el método que me queda para crear es el `resetStatistics()`. Este método tiene que instanciar un nuevo objeto `StatisticsTeam` pero no acabo de entender a qué se refiere con "instanciar".

Actualmente, he diseñado la clase `Team` de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Team {
    private int id;
    private static int nextId = 0;
    private String name;
    private String foundationYear;
    private String nif;
    private String email;
    private int capacity;

    public Team() throws Exception {
        this.setId();
        this.setName("Lorem club");
        this.setFoundationYear("2000");
        this.setNif("G12345678");
        this.setEmail("info@yourmail.com");
        this.setCapacity(21);
    }

    public Team(String name, String foundationYear, String nif, String email, int capacity) throws Exception {
        this.setId();
        this.setName(name);
        this.setFoundationYear(foundationYear);
        this.setNif(nif);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setCapacity(capacity);
    }

       //SETTERS Y GETTERS 

       //Faltaría añadir el método resetStatistics() y 
       //getStatisticsTeam() a los ya creados 
       //pero no sé cómo hacerlo/entiendo el concepto.
```

Comment: Instancias un objeto cuando usas el `new NombreObjeto()`, eso es a lo que se refiere. Basicamente creas un objeto (*instancia*) nuevo. Tienes que crear la clase StatisticsTeam, y en el método `resetStatistics()` basicamente creas un nuevo `StatisticsTeam` y lo asignas a donde corresponda :)

Comment: Si ya he creado la clase StatisticsTeam también en otro fichero Java pero como soy nuevo en el tema de asociaciones... pues no acabo de verlo :)

Comment: Nuevo? Pero si ya lo has hecho al menos 7 veces... es exactamente lo mismo que `private String name`, pero con tu clase e instanciándolo: `private StatisticsTeam statistics;` y en el constructor puedes usar `this.statistics = new StatisticsTeam();`, o directamente declararlo así `private StatisticsTeam statistics = new StatisticsTeam();`. No hay ninguna diferencia entre `String` y una clase creada por ti, excepto el nombre.... por lo demás, todo es lo mismo!